# Azure, AWS, sync services, databases and iOS

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, azure, amazon-web-services, synchronization

I'm starting the development of a new iPhone application that will require the app to synchronize its data model with a web application. This is the first time that I've attempted such a task.

The internal data model is fairly simple - a handful of entities  with a couple of one-to-many mappings.

I've been looking at various options to handle the server side of things, however my investigation into Windows Azure and the Sync Service Framework is driving me nuts. I'm hoping that someone can help clear things up for me.

1) Is it possible to create a scaleable web application, hosted on Windows Azure, integrating the Microsoft's sync services? I'm getting confused by the services that Azure can offer vs the services that you'd have to install on your own server. Can anyone point me to the right pages? At the moment the only Sync Service stuff I can find would require me to install Sync Services on a Windows box, so I'm getting rather confused.

2) Is there an iOS SDK + example that will let me set up a web service on Azure and synchronize a basic database (Core Data, SQLite or otherwise).

3) Assuming the above is possible, what would I then need to do to have a Web app hosted that'd have access to this data.

Finally, does AWS offer anything similar. I discovered the SimpleDB offering and sample iOS app, but the future of SimpleDB looks vague and I don't wish to develop my app around it.

I also looked at Google App Engine but I can't find any sync frameworks to provide a starting point. As an indie developer I can't invest the amount of time required to role out my own.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 4):

I recently implemented a sync system with Windows Azure and multi platform clients:

- Clients are WP7, iOS and Android
- Data is stored in [Windows Azure Table Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179423.aspx)
- Using the [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) we expose a common API for synchronization (uploading and downloading changes, asking for a full reset, authentication, ...)
- All clients use SQLite for local persistence and interact with he ASP.NET Web API using JSON

We decided not to go with the Sync framework because it seemed to limit our flexibility of the synchronization system. Because we are supporting millions of devices we decided to go for a custom sync implementation using the power of table storage (with  partitons per user for example).

Anyways, with the new update of the SDK it will be easy to create an API (be it in .NET or any other language) and to persist your data in a reliable performing way (be it Table Storage, MongoDB, ...).

To answer your second question I don't know if there's a full example to do this, but this might get you started:

1. SQLite on iOS: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application
2. JSON in iOS: http://stig.github.com/json-framework/
3. ASP.NET Web API and iOS: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_m9kEI3s3-k
4. Table Storage tutorial: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/

To host all this you would need a Windows Azure subscription:

- You can start small with a simple website (free at the moment) to host your API: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/ (once your service gets popular you will need to upgrade to Web/Worker roles).
- A [storage account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433066.aspx) (you only pay for what you use, try to go for the trial which gives you 90 days limited free storage).

If you decide to go for a non-ASP.NET Web API implementation you could even do everything from your Mac thanks to the new features: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/06/07/windows-azure-command-line-tool-for-mac-and-linux.aspx

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your detailed response - I've taken some time to go through the various links. One thing that isn't clear to me is whether  or not requests to the table storage are automatically sent to location that's local to the user (for performance and scaling), or is the server's location is fixed. That aside, the biggest problem is that it leaves me with the hardest part of the implementation - the database synchronization....

Comment: tarmes, requests to table storage are always sent to a specific storage account, which is located in one data center. You can achieve some global distribution/caching of blob storage through Azure's CDN service, but not table storage.